# Slicing elements from three select menus into and out of array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, select, slice

```js
var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
var select2 = document.getElementById('select2');
var array = [];
let sel1 = false;

function myFunct1() { 
  var one = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
  if(array.length === 1 && !sel1) array.unshift(one);
  else array.splice(0,1,one);
  console.log(array);
  sel1 = true;
}

function myFunct2() {
  var two = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
  array.splice(sel1, 1, two);
  console.log(array);
}

            function myFunct3() {
                var three = select3.options[select3.selectedIndex].value;
            }
```

```html
<select id = 'select1' onchange = 'myFunct1()'>
            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value = 'Dog1'>Dog</option>
            <option value = 'Cat1'>Cat</option>
            <option value = 'Bear1'>Bear</option>
            </select>
            
        <select id = 'select2' onchange = 'myFunct2()'>
            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value = 'Dog2'>Dog</option>
            <option value = 'Cat2'>Cat</option>
            <option value = 'Bear2'>Bear</option>
            </select>
                    
        <select id = 'select3' onchange = 'myFunct3()'>
            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value = 'Dog3'>Dog</option>
            <option value = 'Cat3'>Cat</option>
            <option value = 'Bear3'>Bear</option>
            </select>
```

I have this method that works exactly how I want it with two select menus. So if you select twice in a row from the second select the array's length is never more than one until you select from the first. Now I want to incorporate a third select menu. Please help me make this work. I'm aware I could combine them all into one function and not have to deal with these issues but for my use, I can't do that. The main condition is that there is never multiple selections within the array from the same select menu and never any empty positions within the array that still count towards its length. so an array of [undefined, Cat2] does not occur.

Comment: `myFunct3` isn't defined in your script..

Comment: sorry I messed it up. The question is correct now I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is:

- Create two arrays i.e `realArr`(to keep strings at original indexes). For example value from `select1` will always we set to `realArr[0]` and from `select2` to `realArr[1]`...
- Second array `showArr` is array from which you will remove `undefined` using `filter()`

```js
var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
        var select2 = document.getElementById('select2');
        var select3= document.getElementById('select3');
        var realArr = [];
        var showArr = [];
        
        function myFunct1() { 
            var one = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
            realArr[0] = one;
            showArr = realArr.filter(x => x !== undefined);
            console.log(showArr);
        }
        
        function myFunct2() {
            var two = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
            realArr[1] = two
            showArr = realArr.filter(x => x !== undefined);
            console.log(showArr);
        }


        function myFunct3() {
            var three = select3.options[select3.selectedIndex].value;
            realArr[2] = three;
            showArr = realArr.filter(x => x !== undefined);
            console.log(showArr);
        }
```

```html
<select id = 'select1' onchange = 'myFunct1()'>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value = 'Dog1'>Dog</option>
        <option value = 'Cat1'>Cat</option>
        <option value = 'Bear1'>Bear</option>
        </select>
        
    <select id = 'select2' onchange = 'myFunct2()'>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value = 'Dog2'>Dog</option>
        <option value = 'Cat2'>Cat</option>
        <option value = 'Bear2'>Bear</option>
        </select>
                
    <select id = 'select3' onchange = 'myFunct3()'>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value = 'Dog3'>Dog</option>
        <option value = 'Cat3'>Cat</option>
        <option value = 'Bear3'>Bear</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: @Harper Creek Your question was a bit tricky one. Because when the element is added to array we can't say from which select it is.

Comment: ahhh maheer it's you. You came up with this better way? That's awesome, thanks for all the help again. Btw in this code above ^^^ you defined select3 as select2 by mistake. I would edit it but it says an edit needs to be more than 6 characters for me. :)

Comment: @Harper Creek I have fixed that.